# Как сохранить принятые json данные?

Tags: python, json

Помогите разобраться. Все перепробовал и не как не могу сохранить принятые данные в файл. Вот код:

```
def url():
    response = requests.get('https://btc-e.nz/api/3/ticker/usd_rur')
    print(response.json())
```

Comment: А что выводит `print(response.json())` ?

Comment: Вам просто сохранить response.json() как строку, или в каком-то определенном формате?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам не нужно проверять, что сервер вернул именно JSON формат, то метод `.json()` можно не вызывать, а сразу сохранить ответ на диск:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()
r.raw.decode_content = True  # support Content-Encoding e.g., gzip
with open('response.json', 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, file)  # copy in chunks, it works for large files
```

Код с `r.json()` загружает JSON документ с http-сервера, распознаёт его целиком в памяти и тут же сохраняет на диск:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'
r = requests.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()
data = r.json()  # do not create the result file until json is parsed
with open('response.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Опции `indent=2, ensure_ascii=False` использованы, чтобы для улучшить читаемость для людей.

Первый вариант меньше работы выполняет (и меньше проверок). Второй вариант гарантирует, что ответ как JSON распознать можно и поэтому вероятно является предпочтительным, если особых требований нет.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте через `json.dump` сохранить в файл:

```
import json
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response.json(), outfile)
```

Comment: да спасибо огромное,а то перепробовал все методы и ни как не мог сохранить,а сейчас все нормально функционирует!

Answer (score -2):

Вот так надо -

```
def url():
    response = requests.get('https://btc-e.nz/api/3/ticker/usd_rur')
    example = response.json()
    print(example)
```

Comment: И куда мы их сохранили:?

Comment: Вы сохраняете результаты в переменную example и потом выводим это

Comment: Цитата из вопроса: >Все перепробовал и не как не могу сохранить принятые данные в **файл**

Comment: так не работает у 3xx python