# Получение картинки c помощью requests

Tags: python, requests

Написал такой код для загрузки картинки с сайта и последующим сохранением ее в файл:

```
import requests

with open('newfile.jpg','wb') as target:
    a = requests.post('http://sphinx-ru.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/_images/git-img-007a.png')
    target.write(a.raw)
```

При запуске вылетает TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_requests.py", line 4, in <module>
target.write(a.raw)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'HTTPResponse'
```

Comment: Вас не смущает что вы пытаетесь сохранить png-картинку в файл с расширение jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать не `a.raw`, а `a.content`:

```
import requests

with open('newfile.jpg','wb') as target:
    a = requests.post('http://sphinx-ru.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/_images/git-img-007a.png')
    target.write(a.content)
```

Comment: POST http запрос по ссылке png-картинки не вернёт вам jpeg. Более того это приводит к ошибке 405 Not  Allowed. Используйте `requests.get()` и `.png` расширение.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сохранить картинку по частям, можно `stream=True` и `copyfileobj()` использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shutil
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/picture.png'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()
r.raw.decode_content = True  # support Content-Encoding e.g., gzip
with open('picture.png', 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, file)  # copy in chunks, it works for large files
```

Связанный вопрос: [Как сохранить принятые json данные?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/656636/23044)