# Как правильно получить картинку капчи?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, распознавание-символов, bs4

Привет.

Есть задача отправить форму с защищённую капчей.

[Здесь](http://sma.lsm99.net/captcha/securimage_show.php?sid=09fbfd4ee4ae0a646b688ce78ee68347) сама капча и можно увидеть, что `src` в `img` имеет такое значение: `http://sma.lsm99.net/captcha/securimage_show.php?sid=09fbfd4ee4ae0a646b688ce78ee68347`

Написал скрипт, который эту капчу распознаёт:

```
import pytesseract
import sys
import argparse
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
from subprocess import check_output


def resolve(path):
    check_output(['convert', path, '-resample', '600', path])
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path))


if __name__=="__main__":
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument('path',help = 'Captcha file path')
    args = argparser.parse_args()
    path = args.path
    print('Распознавание капчи')
    captcha_text = resolve(path)
    print('Полученный результат',captcha_text)
```

И всё хорошо срабатывает. Но если я использую `BS4`:

```
response = requests.get(URL, auth=(username, password), verify=False)

page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(page)


# Сохраняем в файловой системе
with open(basename('image.png'), "wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(page).content)

return True
```

То результат `print(page)` получается специфический:

```
IHDRK�jDA�IDATX��X]K*]^�LbIC�T�E!b���}��vt�E���E7��.���C    ������
                                                                       �F���Bs:�3
                                                                                  j:�y9�����^{�zf��מ�����?���9������������Y$�D*��d254\�������e�ϗB������
                                                                                                                                                             Y���������I$���������ϝN����V�-++˹�V�DH��z��p�a�L������-�
����FF��X����0���:99���ɹCn����Yf�ٲ���p8X��f�����z�����")�r�ݡ
������F�p<??�,��h
�����v;7          C}}}qqq(��ؠi��t
        �@����b�����Cyy9<>&gt;
�*�
��t2�-..2
          �aGVVV������rLMM������EQ|��h��p���`kk+x&lt;���p8���q�,�ry(����j�
                                                                                  �
                                                                                      QX`?&lt;99A��noo��C�J�H�$I2�L��z��"��b��b����d�$I�%�������k�ab�������*���
   q��,�x&lt;��-���������{A�$���M&amp;G�L���K��WVV8���
B��;�///^��Fcv���u���J%*�H@Z��!��t���~����˲8����,f6�����F#����������ŐeY�wKK�ϟ��][[�䍎��d
                                                                                                    W��&amp;���-���I$WWW+++,�!0K�!I�ooo��&amp;�kkk(9�fsJ���x&lt;�F�2��#3'˲n��B1&gt;&gt;.����N�K�'��������}�ry8�B|���&amp;������t�`0���
vww������7F�Z}ssCQ��@Q��������I�N�#���WWW���e4�z���t:Sf����������$�J%wk#Ið�X�0�]\\���
                                                                                             8����������&gt;���!����`{{["����
������u��b|��_��W�
                    �\�ē0XIEND�B`�'
```

А в ФС сохраняется пустой текстовый файл.

При этом, если вы пройдёте по ссылке, то увидите `html`, а если пройти по ссылки скриптом, то нету вообще `DOM'a`

Буду крайне признателен за любую помощь.

Заранее спасибо вам.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Проблемы была не в ссылке, а в том, что я не то пытался сохранить.

```
def parse_image(URL):
    response = requests.get(URL)

    with open(basename('capcha.png'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)

    return response.status_code
```

Сейчас картинка сохраняется как надо, но есть другая проблема.

Так как для сохранения картинки нужно делать ещё один запрос, картинка сменяется, и при отправки формы, я получаю ошибку о не правильной капче.

Первый запрос отправляется на саму страницу `login`, и там уже есть картинка с капчей. Второй запрос отправляется для того, чтобы из этого адреса ( `src` в `img` ) получить саму картинку.

Не понимаю, как это правильно сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите комментарии к каждой строчке в вашем коде с BS4, а то я не могу понять, что он по вашей задумке должен делать

Comment: Судя по `IHDR`, `IDAT` и `IEND` в `print(page)` вам прилетает не html страница а сама картинка в  формате [png](http://wiki.metrotek.spb.ru/wiki/PNG_-_%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE). Хотя странно что после `IEND` ещё что-то идёт.

Comment: старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос. Если у вас возникла новая проблема, задайте новый вопрос (можно для контекста сослаться на текущий вопрос, но вся необходимая для ответа информация должна быть в самом новом вопросе).

Comment: @jfs, без проблем :) Я думал, что это. наоборот, только хуже.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik: проблема с  `BeautifulSoup(png_data)` кодом никак не связана с тем что *"картинка меняется"*

Comment: Проблема связана с requests.get(image_url).content

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка у вас возвращает картинку (двоичные данные), а не html. Бессмысленно пытаться интерпретировать картинку (в png формате) как текст (`response.text`) и бессмысленно пытаться как html распознать (`BeautifulSoup`).

У вас уже в коде есть правильный способ сохранить картинку (`f.write(response.content)`). См. [Получение картинки c помощью requests](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/696303/23044).

Более того, если вам только текст нужен из картинки, то вообще не обязательно её на диск сохранять, можно прямо в памяти картинку получить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests  # $ pip install requests
import pytesseract  # $ sudo apt install tesseract-ocr && pip install pytesseract
from PIL import Image  # $ pip install pillow

url = 'https://example.com/path/to/filename.png'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True  # handle spurious Content-Encoding
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r.raw))
print(text)
```

См. [temporarily retrieve an image using the requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32853980/4279)

Comment: Да, но проблема в том, что отправляется 2 запроса, и капча меняется с каждым из запросов.

В Вашем примере вы уже отправляете запрос, где урл - путь до картинки. Но прежде чем этот урл получить, мне нужно зайти на урл с формой.

Comment: Вариант, который я нашёл - это использовать селениум, чтобы сделать снимок экрана, с которого, собственно, и получить капчу, без повторной отправки запроса.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik: как я уже выше в комментарии написал, это отдельная проблема. Решайте одну проблему за раз: нашли ответ на один вопрос, задайте следующий (так ответы на ваши вопросы ещё кому-нибудь могут пригодиться -- причина по которой Stack Overflow существует)