# Распознавание номера телефона на картинке

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, распознавание-образов

Как можно распознать номер телефона на картинке?

Comment: Чем pytesseract не понравился?)

Comment: @diraria хотелось посмотреть на другие решения) Но раз ничего другого не предложили, ваша заслуженная награда

Comment: Спасибо! Я пробовал искать, как это сделать на opencv, но понял, что там слишком сложно)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Например, [pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract):

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

import io
import requests

image_bytes = requests.get('http://placehold.it/200x100').content
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(text)  # 200x100
```

Comment: можно `Image.open(r.raw)` использовать, если `stream=True` в `requests.get()` передать. См. [Как правильно получить картинку капчи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706255/23044)

Comment: @jfs спасибо, я так понимаю в этом случае будет на одно копирование меньше?

Comment: не знаю как реализовано. Возможно, что внутри `io.BytesIO` всё равно используется.