# Автокликер на python?

Tags: python

Есть ли модуль по управлению мышью автоматизированно. Что-то типа автокликера по координатам x, y.

Comment: Например, [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput). А вообще, нельзя использовать слово `библиотека` в вопросах, иначе вопрос могут закрыть :)

Comment: [в selenium...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887320/5741205)

Comment: огромное спасибо, насчёт библиотек в следующий раз учту

Comment: @diraria, бредовое предположение. Вопрос, сводящийся просто к поиску библиотеки закроют даже если слово "библиотека" не будет явно присутствовать в вопросе.

Comment: @personality13, если я скажу, что вопросы по поиску модулей, библиотек, программ, книг оффтопичны на этом сайте, то слово "модуль" вы тоже удалите?)

Comment: @insolor, вот же совсем недавно был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715502/227016), который закрыли [**только**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5863/227016) потому что в вопросе была слова библиотека

Comment: @diraria, если в вопросе не описана конкретная проблема, а просто вопрос сводится к поиску чего-то в интернете - это это оффтопик, не важно есть ли в нем слово "библиотека" или нет. Если в вопросе есть конкретная проблема, то вопрос уже нельзя просто так закрыть.

Comment: @insolor, хорошо-хорошо, не буду спорить