# Распознавание текста в питоне - поддержка русского и простота

Tags: python, распознавание-символов

Какие есть библиотеки под питон, чтобы распознать текст (НЕ рукописный, а скриншот экрана) ?

Хотелось бы:

Поддержка русского

Максимальная простота

Comment: связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715533/227016

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Распознавание номера телефона на картинке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715502/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: @AndrioSkur распознавание цифр не требует русского языка, поэтому не дубликат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Teseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) подходит под ваши требования. [Тут](https://goldvoice.club/@vp-webdev/raspoznavanie-teksta-na-izobrazhenii/) можно почитать как установить модуль для поддержки русского языка и посмотреть пример использования.

Comment: Гляньте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837238/tesseractnotfounderror-tesseract-is-not-installed-or-its-not-in-your-path

Comment: цифры не расопзнаются у меня