# TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

Tags: python, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Инсталлировал тессеракт попробывал запустить, сразу получаю такую ошибку.
Как побороть ? Возможно, надо дополнительно делать pip install tesseract-ocr, - так ли это ?  (Который у меня не ставится из-за ошибки, что нет MS-Studio 14)

```
import pytesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(t)
```

Это выдает ошибку:
TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

Детали:

Работаю под анакондой, виндовс, юпитер.
Инсталлировал командой 
pip install pytesseract
(как указано https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ )
запуск из каталога Anaconda3\Scripts\  (обычно так делаю и работают)

После ошибки попробывал дополнительно инсталлировать 
pip install tesseract
прошло без ошибок но не помогает,
дополнительно

pip install tesseract-ocr 
у меня не ставится из-за ошибки, что нет MS-Studio 14

---

ПС

pip3 - у меня не находится под анакондой

ПСПС
Аналогичный вопрос был вчера задан и на английской версии сайта:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/tesseract-not-found-error
но ответ не ясен,
если написать как предложено: 
from tesseract import image_to_string
то это вызывает синтакс эррор:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-25-e72b4376f6a2>", line 3, in <module>
    from tesseract import image_to_string

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tesseract\__init__.py", line 34
    print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: дык, а `tesseract` то сам ты установил? если верить секции `INSTALLATION ` [в доках](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), то он устанавливается отдельно, а питоний модуль — всего лишь морда к обычному бинарнику. Под nix'ами обычно он есть в репах; под виндой — см. соответствующие доки...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо за комментарий. Нет не установил. Не совсем понял секцию  INSTALLATION в доках. Не подскажите, что сделать надо ?

Comment: Надо установить саму либу и консольную морду к ней (`tesseract.exe`); подробно об установке под win я не расскажу, так что просто отошлю к соответствующим [докам](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki). После этого не забудь добавить путь к `tesseract.exe` в `PATH`, как сказано в ошибке в соседнем вопросе... ЗЫ: почитай доки по tesseract — для нормального распознавания изображению нужна будет какая-ни какая предобработка...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо ! что значит предобработка ? надо будет обучать на каких-то текстах ? Надеюсь нет. У меня очень простой текст, скришот экрана. Что значит установить "саму либу" это pip install ?

Comment: предварительно обработать изображение — скорей всего в данном случае будет достаточно просто обесцветить, возможно также баланс белого чуть-чуть подправить... либа должна поставиться вместе с экзешником — в данном случае напрямую скорей всего использоваться не будет. Упомянул её просто для комплекта...

Answer (score 1):

Тоже сталкивался с такой ошибкой. Согласен с комментарием @Fat-Zer:

> Надо установить саму библиотеку и консольный интерфейс к ней (tesseract.exe).
> Подробно об установке под Windows в соответствующей [документации](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki).
>
> После этого не надо забыть добавить путь к tesseract.exe в `PATH`, как сказано в ошибке в [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655738/tesseract-not-found-error) на английском SO.
>
> PS: Советую почитать документацию по tesseract — для нормального распознавания изображений нужна будет какая ни какая предобработка.