# Как распознать текст с изображения?

Tags: python, изображения, текст

у меня возникла такая проблема. Хочу написать программу для распознавания и считывания текста с изображения (по типу капчи). Я использую Python. Какую нужно использовать библиотеку и как считать текст, не скачивая саму картинку (когда она просто высветилось в браузере)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706255/355827

Comment: Ого го. Как загнул то! Тут просто невозможно обойти нейронные сети. Плюс тебе придется горы покорить. То есть капча специально придумана для того, чтобы машина ее не смогла прочитать. Но, безусловно, не безнадежное дело. Много нового о нейронках узнаешь.

Comment: Если задаёте такие вопросы, значит вы ещё совсем сырой и к этому не готовы ну никак

Comment: Задачи распознавания аудио-видео требуют использования AI, либо универсального инструмента - школьников, зарабатывающих гроши на распознавании капчи))

Answer (score 1):

небольшой пример:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<path>\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r'img\small_pack\pil\3.png'), lang="rus"))
```

- [pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract)
- [tesseract.exe](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc)

Comment: Ему необходимо считывать изображения на лету, не из папки. А указанный tesseract довольно медлительный, не всегда точен и точно не подходит для большего кол-ва имеющихся вариантов капчи. Автору нужно чтобы код помимо всего связанно с распознаванием еще и парсил контент, откуда потом уже брать изображения и пути к ним. Мне кажется, как написали ранее, простого решения нет.

Comment: Я был невнимателен при прочтении вопроса, сегодня не мой день..(