# pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытался решить эту проблему, попробовав все способы, пытался указать путь, перезагружал Пк, переустанавливал библиотеку - ничего не работает...

Вывод при любом коде связанным с этой библиотекой:

```
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 238, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\WorkAI\WA.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string('images.txt'))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 360, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 359, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 270, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 242, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH
```

Есть ли другие библиотеки для распознавания текста?

Comment: *>попробовав все способы* - опишите, **как** Вы пробовали.

Comment: ^^^ И желательно ещё привести код, который у вас был *до того*, как вы пытались решить проблемы с ним

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138842/234134