# Как скачать файл, если нет прямой ссылки? Python request

Tags: python, файлы, requests, download, xlsx

Есть следующий get запрос на скачивание xlsx файла:

`https://seller.wildberries.ru/ns/api/suppliers-portal-feedbacks-questions/api/v1/questions/report?isAnswered=false`

На выходе я получаю параметры fileName, contentType и **file**. Сам file состоит из **8 тысяч символов**.

Были попытка записать файл следующим образом:

```
import requests

cookies = ... # тут я передаю куки-файлы

response = requests.get(url='https://seller.wildberries.ru/ns/api/suppliers-portal'
                              '-feedbacks-questions/api/v1/questions/report?isAnswered=false',
                          cookies=cookie)
with open(response.json()['data']['fileName'], 'wb') as file:
   file.write(b"test.json()['data']['file']")
```

Но это не помогает. Я попробовал разные методы, однако ничего не увенчалось успехом (декодировал строку и т.д.). В загрузках Chrome показывает, что скачивание файла происходит по blob ссылке, но её связать с получаемыми по get запросу данными я никак не могу.

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656636/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-json-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить не requests.get, а requests.head и посмотреть, что вам прилетает в заголовках. Может быть в них есть ссылка для переадресации, которая находиться в "Location". Проверить, к сожалению, нет возможности. так как там нужно регистрироваться как организации ))

Comment: file.write(response.json()['file'])

Comment: @СергейКох там идет сохранение обычно JSON, а мне нужен файл расширения .xlsx.

Comment: @Евгений в request head ноль информации, к сожалению. В Location ничего нет, а точнее, самого  Location нет.

Comment: @СергейШ так и было, просто в ответе неправильно записал. Тоже не работает.